# Update Css Class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, getelementbyid

Can't update color of class dynamically.

By the way, the code works fine without having class, but on case having class, it does not work.

```js
    function myFunction() {
    var cssColor=".MyClass h1{background-color:pink;color:black;}  .MyClass p{background-color:pink;color:white;}";
     cssColor = cssColor.replace('pink', document.getElementById("txtColor").value);
    document.getElementById("mainBody").style.cssText = cssColor;
    document.getElementById("mainBody").classList.add = cssColor;
    document.getElementById('mainBody').className = 'MyClass';
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body id="mainBody" >
    
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p >This is a paragraph.</p>
    
     <input type="text" name="txtColor" id="txtColor"  style="display: inline-block;width: 50px; height:30px;direction: ltr" maxlength="7">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set style for p</button>
    
  
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: do you explain what the actually problem  in code, which type of problem you facing

Comment: `.classList.add(cssColor)` — it's a function

Comment: @PointyI changed to `document.getElementById("mainBody").classList.add('MyClass');` but nothing change and it's not works

Comment: @AMARMAGAR I try to change color of my project. So my project has many class and this is a sample for learning. tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with that code:

1. `add` on `classList` is a **function**, you don't assign to it, you call it:

   ```
   document.getElementById('mainBody').classList.add('MyClass');
   ```
2. Your next statement assigns to `className`, which will wipe out the call to `classList.add`. So one of them or the other should be removed.
3. The `.style.cssText` property on the `body` element contains inline styles for `body`, **not** a stylesheet. What you're assigning to it is stylesheet text. You'd put that in a `style` element (or in a separate `.css` file and link it with a `link` element).

It's hard to help you with positive suggestions because it's not clear what you want to do. **If** you want to apply those styles to the page, updating `pink` to the color the user inputs, you can have a `style` element and update its text content. I wouldn't use `pink`, though, I'd use some token like `%%COLOR%%`. I'd also use modern event handling rather than an `onclick` attribute, something along these lines:

```js
var css =
  "h1 { " +
  "    background-color: %%COLOR%%; " +
  "    color: black; " +
  "} " +
  "p { " +
  "    background-color: %%COLOR%%; " +
  "    color: white; " +
  "}";

function setStyleToColor(color) {
    document.getElementById("the-style").textContent = css.replace(/%%COLOR%%/g, color);
}

function myFunction() {
    setStyleToColor(document.getElementById("txtColor").value);
}
setStyleToColor("pink");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

```html
<style id="the-style"></style>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>

<input type="text" name="txtColor" id="txtColor"  style="display: inline-block;width: 50px; height:30px;direction: ltr" maxlength="7">
<button type="button">Set style for p</button>
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> I try to change color of my project

I would do that by having multiple separate stylesheets (`pink.css`, `blue.css`) and using a `link` element to link them to the project. Updating the style becomes removing the old link and setting the new one.

Answer (score 0):

This will change the color of your p tag. You could also assign a class to all paragraphs you want to color, and then loop through it via the `each`-loop.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var pColor = "color:white;"
  pColor = pColor.replace('white', document.getElementById("txtColor").value);

  document.getElementById("paragraph").style.cssText = pColor;

  document.getElementById('mainBody').className = 'MyClass';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body id="mainBody">

  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p id="paragraph">This is a paragraph.</p>

  <input type="text" name="txtColor" id="txtColor" style="display: inline-block;width: 50px; height:30px;direction: ltr" maxlength="7">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set style for p</button>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As I said it's works fine when we haven't class, but what about `h1`, what about having many elements on a body, I looking to change by using class. tnx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,  You can have style blocks in the document head. And keep updating the inner text to update the styles

```js
var style = document.createElement("style");
var cssColor=
 ".MyClass h1{background-color:pink;color:black;}  .MyClass p{background-color:pink;color:white;}";
document.head.appendChild(style);

function myFunction() {
  cssColor = cssColor.replace('pink', document.getElementById("txtColor").value);
  style.innerText = cssColor;
  document.getElementById('mainBody').className = 'MyClass';
}
```